# Can I redirect the Admin->abc.aspx to rootfolder->index.aspx using javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Just explaining my question in short.

I have asp.net website with root structure as following

```
root Directory->
    Admin
        abc.aspx
        xyz.aspx
    index.aspx
```

Now I want to redirect from `abc.aspx` to `index.aspx`.

I'm using JavaScript as

```
window.location = "../index.aspx";
```

but found no any luck.

Comment: If I enter `javascript:window.location = "../index.aspx";` in the address bar here, I get redirected to `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/index.aspx` so it should work.

Comment: I have tried "javascript:window.location = "../index.aspx"; but still  its remains in same directory searching for index.aspx and HTTP 404 error occurred.

Comment: @Sagar Please provide the URL along with folder structure clearly.

Comment: Ok. Here it is. I have root directory with website name; say Website1. In root directory I have index.aspx page. Then I have added one directory called Admin. In Admin directory I have some pages like adminhome.aspx....  Now i want redirect from adminhome.aspx to index.aspx using purely javascript no hidden field or anything like that.

Comment: Ok, One last question. Is the application created as virtual directory or website?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very odd trick. But it works.

Have a hidden field in the page. This needn't be a server control. (Or if you want, you can even do without one.). For brevity sake I am assuming you've used a server HiddenField control, called `hfNavUrl`. Do something like this.

```
hfNavUrl.Value = Me.ResolveUrl("~/index.aspx")
```

Once this renders you get the full url. Find the hidden field value in javascript and work your javascript code:

```
window.location.href = document.getElementByValue('hfNavUrl').value;
```

### Update: Doing it w/o using controls

There are two ways about this. However, you'd have to [embed the code](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976112) in your page markup file (i.e. the *.aspx file). The javascript way is something like holding the url into a variable.

```
var url = '<%= Me.ResolveUrl("~/index.aspx") %>';
```

You can now make use of the value inside of this variable at a later point of time.

Alternatively, you can simply have a `<a>` element with its `href` set directly:

```
<a href="<%= Me.ResolveUrl("~/Index.aspx") %>">Home</a>
```

Ps: `Me.`whatever is the vb.net way of doing things. Replace it with `this` if you are working with c#

Comment: This will be useful but I have to use another hidden control n all that. Will it be not possible through javascript only.

Answer (score 0):

You issue will be resolved by one of the below solutions from java script by providing the type of application.

If Application created as Website

```
windows.location='/index.aspx';
```

and

If Application created as Virtual directory

```
windows.location='/[Virtual Directory Name of Root Folder]/index.aspx';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using "window.location.replace('/index.aspx')"